Almost all random bipartite graph is a regular pair
Given a bipartite graph $(A,B)$, the edge density between $A$ and $B$ is $$d(A,B) := \frac{e(A,B)}{|A| |B|}.$$
A regular pair (or $\varepsilon$-regular pair) $(A,B)$ is a bipartite graph such that for every $A'\subseteq A$ and $B' \subseteq B$ with $|A'| \ge \varepsilon |A|$ and $|B'| \ge \varepsilon |B|$,
$$ |d(A',B') - d(A,B)| < \varepsilon.$$
Let $G = (A,B)$ be a random bipartite graph, where each edge between $A$ and $B$ is chosen with probability $p$ independently. As $|A|,|B| \to \infty$, show that, almost surely (i.e., the probability goes to $1$)
(a) $|d(A,B) - p| < \varepsilon$, for any constant $\varepsilon > 0$.
(b) $(A,B)$ is an $\varepsilon$-regular pair for any constant $\varepsilon >0$.
This is Exercise 13.3.7 in Bondy & Murty's GTM 244.

(a)
Let $X_e$ be the indicator random variable of the edge $e$, i.e., $X_e = 1$ if $e \in E(G)$ and $X_e$ otherwise.
And $\mathbb{E}[X_e] = p \cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0 = p$, and $\text{Var}(X_e) = \mathbb{E}[X_e^2] - \mathbb{E}[X_e]^2 = p - p^2$.
Let $X = \sum_{e} X_e$ be the number of edges in $G$.
Then, $d(A,B) = \frac{X}{|A||B|}$.
Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[d(A,B)] = \sum_{e} \mathbb{E}[X_e] / |A||B| = p$.
Since $X_e$ are mutually independent, $\text{Cov}(X_e,X_{e'}) = 0$ for all $e \ne e'$.
Hence, $\text{Var}(X) = \sum_{e} \text{Var}(X_e) + \sum_{e \ne e'} \text{Cov}(X_e,X_{e'}) = (p-p^2) |A||B|$.
By the Chebyshev's inequality:
$$ \mathbb{P}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \ge t] \le \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{t^2}$$
With $t = \varepsilon |A| |B|$, we obtain
$$ \mathbb{P}[|d(A,B) - p| \ge \varepsilon] = \mathbb{P}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]| \ge \varepsilon |A||B|] \le \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\varepsilon^2 |A|^2 |B|^2} = \frac{p-p^2}{\varepsilon^2 |A| |B|} \to 0$$
(b) Need to apply the Chernoff inequality: if $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ where $X_i$ are mutually independent random variables such that $X_i = 1$ with probability $p_i$ and $X_i = 0$ with probability $1 - p_i$, let $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n p_i$, then we have
$$ \mathbb{P}[X \ge (1+ \delta) \mu] \le e^{- \frac{\delta^2}{2 + \delta} \mu} \quad \text{ for any $\delta > 0$}$$
$$ \mathbb{P}[X \le (1- \delta) \mu] \le e^{- \frac{\delta^2}{2} \mu} \quad \text{ for any $0 < \delta < 1$}$$
As a corollary,
$$ \mathbb{P}[ |X - \mu| \ge \delta \mu] \le 2e^{- \frac{\delta^2}{3}\mu } \quad \text{ for any $0 < \delta < 1$}$$
Back to our random bipartite graph $(A,B)$, for any $A'\subseteq A, B' \subseteq B$ with $|A'| \ge \varepsilon |A|, |B'| \ge \varepsilon |B|$,
$$ \mathbb{P}[|d(A',B') - p| \ge \varepsilon/2] = \mathbb{P}[|e(A',B') - p|A'||B'|| \ge \frac{\varepsilon}2 |A'||B'|]$$
With $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2p}$ and $\mu = p |A'||B'|$ in the Chernoff's inequality, we obtain
$$ \mathbb{P}[|d(A',B') - p| \ge \varepsilon/2] \le 2 e^{- \frac{\delta^2}{3}\mu} = 2 \exp(- \frac{\varepsilon^2}{4p} |A'||B'|) \le 2 \exp(- \frac{\varepsilon^4}{4p} |A||B|)$$
Therefore, by union bound,
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{P}[(A,B) \text{ is an $\varepsilon$-regular pair}]
& \le \mathbb{P}[|d(A',B') - p| < \varepsilon/2 \text{ for all $A'\subseteq A,B'\subseteq B$ with $|A'| \ge \varepsilon |A|, |B'|\ge \varepsilon |B|$}] \\
& \le \sum_{A'\subseteq A} \sum_{B'\subseteq B} \mathbb{P}[|d(A',B') - p| < \varepsilon/2] \\
& \le 2^{|A|} 2^{|B|} \cdot 2 \exp(- \frac{\varepsilon^4}{4p} |A||B|) \to 0
\end{align*}
where the last step of limit goes to $0$ following from $x + y - cxy \to -\infty$ for any $x,y \to +\infty$.
